# MySQL update on inner/outer join over 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, inner-join, outer-join

I am trying to do an update on an inner join of 2 tables with a where clause.
I currently have a semi working update.  I want to only update a table if 2 conditions are true.  I think i need to have 1 inner and 1 ounter join in order to do this, and I am not sure how to do it.

I have a group of tickets with picks,  I want to add 45 to the tickets that has a specific pick that excludes another.

if a ticket has picks where team_ID = 31 and not team_ID = 49 add 45 to rd_1
if a ticket has picks where team_ID = 49 and not team_ID = 31 subtract 45 to rd_1
if a ticket has both do nothing
if a ticket has neither do nothing

[image]

### ticket

```
ID | rd_1 |
1  | 100  |  
2  | 105  | 
3  | 155  |
```

### picks

```
ID | ticket_ID | team_ID
1  |    1      | 31
2  |    1      | 49
3  |    2      | 31
4  |    2      | 10    
5  |    3      | 49
6  |    3      | 50
```

Expected Results

### ticket

```
ID | rd_1 |
1  | 100  | 
2  | 150  |  
3  | 110  |
```

Here is what I have tried.
This will add 45 to all picks that have a team_ID of 49.  From here I would like to exlude the picks that have a team_ID =31

```
UPDATE database.ticket t INNER JOIN
       database.picks p
       ON t.ID = p.ticket_ID
    SET t.rd_1 = t.rd_1 +45
WHERE p.team_ID = 49;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  ticket t
LEFT JOIN picks p1 ON t.ID = p1.ticket_ID AND p1.team_ID = 31
LEFT JOIN picks p2 ON t.ID = p2.ticket_ID AND p2.team_ID = 49
SET t.rd_1 = CASE
                WHEN p1.ID IS NOT NULL AND p2.ID IS NULL THEN t.rd_1 + 45
                WHEN p1.ID IS NULL AND p2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t.rd_1 - 45
                ELSE t.rd_1
             END;
```

The first `LEFT JOIN` returns matching `31` records, the second one returns matching `49` records. The `CASE` expression examines whether any of the matches really exists and updates the `rd_1` field accordingly.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04038/1)

Comment: Your answer was PERFECT.  You even gave me a new tool to use so you get an upvote to go with it.  Thank you!